# Ruby on Rails - How to add two value in two table into one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables: User, Micropost and Comment. 1 user has many comments, 1 micropost has many comments. 
Problem 1: In model test, I use:

```
@user = users(:michael)
@micropost = microposts(:orange)
@comment = @micropost.comments.build(content: 'a')
```

But @comment can not receive user_id although orange belongs to michael in:

```
orange:
 content: "I just ate an orange!"
 created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
 user: michael
```

How can I receive user_id and micropost_id to Comment table?
This is my comment table:

```
def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :micropost, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :comments, [:user_id, :micropost_id, :created_at]
  end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `@micropost.comments.build(content: 'a', user: @user)`

Comment: Please explain how `@comment` should receive the `user_id`? Nothing tells it to grab it from its `micropost` reference. You will need to provide it yourself or define that it is the same user from the `micropost` which seems not to be your goal.

Comment: @micropost.comments.build(content: 'a', user_id: @micropost.user_id)

Comment: Thanks, I did it!! :)